# Blank space - Quick action

Tags: lightning, quickaction

I have a custom object and I have a built a quick action which will update the status field to "a"

The quick action configuration is shown below

[image]

While designing this quick action, I have this default blank space on the quick action which I do not want and I am not sure how to remove this.

[image]

As you can see this quick action shows an empty space like below

[image]

Can someone let me know how to remove this ?

Comment: This is a Record Update quick action?

Comment: yes that is right

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce Object specific quick action do not have that capability to hide the blank space you are looking for.

From the functionality point of view, user still have to hit the save button.

A better solution would be to use screen flow
[image]

This will executed automatically instead of user clicking on save button. User will just have to close the flow screen.

[image]